# React-gatsby login authentioncation failed

Tags: reactjs, authentication, gatsby

I am using Gatsby for my app. I have created one api from [Mock api](https://designer.mocky.io/). My api looks like [this](https://run.mocky.io/v3/beec46b8-8536-4cb1-9304-48e96d341461). I have made one post-request for login, when user will put his/her email and password, if it does not match then it will alert "failed login" or if it is success it will alert ("successfully login") and navigate to successful page. But what ever email and password I am putting it always shows me I login successfully which is wrong logic. The email should be like my api's email: `alak@gmail.com"` and password: `test123` . I think my logic right but still I am making the mistake. I share my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-microservice-rvl6r).
`PS: Codesandbox is based on react. but logic is same as my below code`

Here is my code:

```
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from 'react';
import { PageProps, navigate } from 'gatsby';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import MainTemplate from '../templates/index';
import { TextInput } from '../components/textInput';
import { Button } from '../components/buttons';
import { API_URLS } from '../utilities';

interface Props extends PageProps {

}

export default function SignIn({ }: Props): ReactElement {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    "email": ``,
    "password": ``,
    "loading": false

  });
  const { loading } = state;
  const signInValue = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    setState({
      "loading": true,
      ...state
    });
    const response = await fetch(`https://run.mocky.io/v3/beec46b8-8536-4cb1-9304-48e96d341461`, {
      "method": `POST`,
      "headers": {
        "Accept": `application/json`,
        'Content-Type': `application/json`
      },
      "body": { state }
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      alert(`you have suceefully login`);
      navigate(`/success`, { "state": { email } });
    } else {
      alert(`login failed`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <MainTemplate>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        value={state.email}
        onChange={signInValue}
        id="email"
        required
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={state.password}
        onChange={signInValue}
        id="password"
        required
      />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        name="action"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        disabled={loading}
      >  {loading ? `loading...` : `save`}
      </Button>

    </MainTemplate>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [fetch specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

So your api might be returning an error but `response.ok` might still be true. You should check `response.status !== 200` instead.

**Update: works as shown below based on your sandbox**:
[image]

Comment: Actually I just tried the url in your question in postman and it's fine I get a 200 response from your API; there must something else wrong in your frontend logic.

Comment: did you see anything in code I am doing wrong?This is the only component I have it in my app

Comment: I share my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-microservice-rvl6r

Comment: @krisna updated answer with correction to your code.

Comment: When I test with wrong email and still said `login sucess`

Comment: @krisna your API endpoint return success no matter what. That has nothing to do with your app. It's just a mock endpoint. It has no logic. It returns the same successful response no matter what you send it.